# How to redirect invitation received to certain folder in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

In lotus notes, there is a option to add rule to a certain email but what I want is to redirect all invitations to single folder. Can you point out to the step-by-step procedure for this?

So far I'm stuck here:

[image]

Comment: I believe this belongs to Super User.

Comment: How can I migrate this to Super User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the QuickRule dialog there is just a subset of all possible options. Please goto Tools-Rules in the left Navigation pane. There you create a normal rule and have a lot more options. Check it out. There you will find a possibility to move invitations. (the form of Invitations ins "Notification")